# Drupal8 set redis keys TTL

Tags: redis, drupal-8

I've been trying to set the TTL for Redis Key from within Drupal, but it does not seem be working. Our settings.php is as follows:

```
// Set Redis as the default backend for any cache bin not otherwise specified.
  $settings['cache']['default'] = 'cache.backend.redis';
  $settings['redis.connection']['interface'] = 'PhpRedis';
  $settings['redis.connection']['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
  $settings['redis.connection']['port'] = '6379';
  $settings['redis.connection']['base'] = 8; // This is the DB ID.
  #$conf['cache_lifetime_redis'] = 21600;
  #$settings['redis.settings']['perm_ttl_cache_field'] = "3 months";
  $conf['redis_perm_ttl'] = "3 months";
```

I've tried with `$conf['cache_lifetime_redis'] = 21600;`, with `$settings['redis.settings']['perm_ttl_cache_field'] = "3 months";` and `$conf['redis_perm_ttl'] = "3 months";` to no avail. When connecting to REDIS, the TTL is still set to 1 year. What else needs to be done to make this work ? settings this at the server level is a no-go, due to being a shared environment.

Comment: You may set TTL for each key separately. as the references say: https://redis.io/commands/set

Comment: @AminShojaei - not sure how that would work. we have millions of keys and need to inject the TTL from Drupal (php code) itself.